# Why is mongoimport.exe is gone from my package?

Tags: mongodb

I'm a begineer at learning MongoDB. I had followed some course and installed windows mongodb enterprise edition package in the downloads section on MongoDB website. After installing and adding environment variables to PATH, I used `mongoimport` command. Then it said `mongodb is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` But I could execute `mongo` command

I had checked C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.4\bin and the only are mongo.exe, mongod.exe, mongodecrypt.exe, mongoldap.exe, and mongos.exe. No others.

So, where can I find downloadable executable file or is there a way to install the rest of the addition tools/package (such as mongodump, mongoimport, mongoexport, and else) so I could do mongoimport?

Comment: you need to install [MONGODB DATABASE TOOLS](https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/) from version 4.4 to use `mongoimport`

Comment: @deadshot thank you so much, I just read that MongoDB 4.4 are separately from the database tools

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same issue myself. As of MongoDB 4.4, the database tools is now a separate installation for all platforms except Linux. You can find the instructions to install for your platform [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/installation/installation/).

Answer (score 1):

I faced same issue. Please find below information might help you to solve your issue related to mongoimport.

The Database Tools are now separately versioned and installed as of the MongoDB 4.4 server release. These tools release independently from the MongoDB Server schedule enabling you to receive more frequent updates and leverage new features as soon as they are available. These include, among other things: mongodump, mongorestore, mongoimport, and mongoexport.

[This is the download link for MongoDB Database Tools](https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/database-tools)

Answer (score 0):

In case of Windows installation, don't forget to add Database Tools folder [to your path](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/installation/installation-windows/#make-the-db-tools-available-in-your-path)